# My discord bot made with python is not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is my code in `main.py`:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN="secret"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents = intents)
  
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{bot.user} successfully logged in!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
      return
      
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def spam(ctx, message, *, amount:int):
  await ctx.send("Starting Spam...")
  new_amount = amount+1
  for i in range(1, new_amount):
    await ctx.send(message)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
  await ctx.send("Spam Completed!")
      
    
try:
    bot.run(TOKEN, bot = False)
except discord.HTTPException as e:
  if e.status == 429:
    print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
  else:
    raise e
```

My bot does go online, however, when I use the spam command, it doesn't work.
The code doesn't give any errors. So I am wondering what the problem is.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is there any error or warning shown on the terminal?

Comment: no, the bot is online but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `message_content` intent set to True. First page of [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) shows you to need to enable the `message_content` intent. This allows your bot to read message content; and therefore actually be able to respond to commands.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)
```

You will also need to enable the `message content` intent in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) as well. Under your application, go to "Bot", and then scroll down to "Privileged Gateway Intents" and then enable the message content one.

[image]

Comment: But then, it gives me this error: 
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    intents.message_content = True
AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'
```
P.S. this is a self bot so there isn't a message content intent.

Comment: Oh, well self-bots are against discord TOS. Commands aren't going to work without being able to read message content so you'll have to figure out your own solution.

Comment: can you give an example of the solution? like should i remove `bot = False` ?

Comment: Well `bot=False` isn't a real parameter, but yes you should remove that. And then you should create a discord application, add a bot user and use that token instead. Then you'll be able to enable intents and have a bot with functional commands. With the bonus of your account not getting banned.

Answer (score -1):

According to discord.py docs:

*"With the API change requiring bot authors to specify intents, some intents were restricted further and require more manual steps. These intents are called **privileged intents**."*

So basically what you need to do is go to the "Bot" section within your application in the discord developers portal and under the heading **Privileged Gateway Intents** you need to enable message content intents etc. based on what your needs are. Also this needs to be done through code as well.

In your case:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
```

needs to be replaced with

```py
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True,message_content=True)
```

or simply

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

Feel free to comment down any queries regarding this solution.

Comment: But this is a self bot and I can't get the message_content=True

Comment: The reason I linked the official docs in my answer was for you to read it which you probably didn't. It was around September last year when discord enforced message content intent for all bots, based on which the forked version of discord.py that you are using must have been updated. If it isn't, it's just the dead end on it's part, and you will have to move to a different up-to-date version of the module.